# Tell protobuf-net to use DataFormat.WellKnown when building model using reflection

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I can't figure out how to tell protobuf-net how to use the Google TimeStamp type instead of the protobuf-net type when building up the model using reflection, in a case where I cannot annotate the classes that should be serialized.

I add the property like this:

```
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default[propertyInfo.DeclaringType].Add(tag, propertyInfo.Name);
```

But if I were annotating the property it would look like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown) ]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I need to tell the **RuntimeTypeModel** to use **DataFormat.WellKnown**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Add` (which is a fluent API), use `AddField`. This returns the `ValueMember` for the field, which includes the `.DataFormat` property.